# How to fetch the recent emails alone from GMail Mail Box using imap class in PHP?

Tags: php, imap, gmail-imap

I would like to fetch email messages from GMail using PHP's imap class.

I tried:

```
$val = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1337352811);
$recentMails = imap_search($this->imapInBox, 'SINCE $val', SE_UID);
```

This did't work.

I tried it with `<SINCE "4 Jun 2012">`. This works.

But I have a problem in downloading attachments when I use this option, and also this will cause redundancy and fetch the same emails again and again. I need to use an accurate time a like Unix time stamp to fetch only the latest emails. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this excerpt from the RFC:

```
  RECENT
     Messages that have the \Recent flag set.

  SINCE <date>
     Messages whose internal date (disregarding time and timezone)
     is within or later than the specified date.
```

You can only search based on the date, not any more granular than that.

What you CAN do however, is unset the `Recent` flag, and search for the date AND `Recent` flag.

Comment: Greg, SEEN and UNSEEN is decided based on manual user click or even reading a mail through IMAP is considered as SEEN?

Comment: greg,  I am using `code` imap_search ($mail, 'UNSEEN SINCE ' . $time . '') `code` and it works fine. Once after reading a mail, I set the \SEEN flag like `code` imap_setflag_full($MBOX, $id, "\\Seen \\Flagged", ST_UID)`code`. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Google "imap phph gmail" and you'll find lots of tutorials and code. For example:
[Retrieve Your Gmail Emails Using PHP and IMAP](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap)

Comment: Panichi, I have perfectly working code. I need a method to fetch only the recent mails. Basically I don't want to fetch the same mail again and again.